Angular Material 3 "Cannot parse the specified color undefined. Please verify it is a hex color"
I have just upgraded an Angular project to latest version as of today (version 18.0.0) including material library using material 3 design. From the documentation here, I am trying to generate a custom theme using the below schematic:
ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme

However I get the bellow error message and I cannot seem to find how to pass the base color as a parameter.
Cannot parse the specified color undefined. Please verify it is a hex color (ex. #ffffff or ffffff).

Have tried different values like --color --c --colour but cannot seem to get it to work and there is no examples on the Angular documentation.
UPDATE
The issue is that the "ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme" command does not work on Windows using Git Bash. Tried the command on normal windows command prompt and it worked fine.

run in your angular project
ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme

when you show message
? What HEX color should be used to generate the M3 theme? It will represent your primary color palette. (ex. #ffffff)

write an hexadecimal color like as
#F1F2F3

Example if case you don't specify hexadecimal color

Working process


Hi @Kemot 90, thanks, however the problem is that when I run "ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme" in my project I get this error message "Cannot parse the specified color undefined. Please verify it is a hex color (ex. #ffffff or ffffff)" instead of the question you mentioned above.

see picture for pratica example

Thanks for adding those screenshots. The problem is that for some reason the command doesn't work on Windows using git bash. I did it again on normal Windows command prompt and it worked fine, I got prompted the questions.
